# Meteor: Find document with highest value

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to just find one document in a collections with the highest value of a specific property.

Assume that documents have the following structure

```
{
  _id: 'jswehfkwefkjw',
  price: 10,
  ....
}
```

How do I select the document with the highest price ?

I found this

```
transactions.find("id" => x).sort({"sellprice" => -1}).limit(1).first();
```

But I cannot translate this into Meteor :( What I have now looks like this

```
Articles.find({}, {sort: {price: -1}}).fetch();
```

But this doesn't do it. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not exactly clear by what you mean in "this doesn't do it".

But I would suggest using findOne instead of fetch, since fetch returns an array and you want a  document.

```
Articles.findOne({}, {sort: {price: -1}});
```

or

```
Articles.find({},{limit: 1, sort: {price: -1}});
```

and then use a fetch and grab the first element using array notation [0] or underscore _.first(array)

Comment: Ok, but how can I do this on the server side, because using `findOne` in a Publish function throws an error

Comment: as @user728291 mentioned you would use the limit option
    Articles.find({},{limit: 1, sort: {price: -1}});
On the client side you can use fetch and then access the first element in array style using [0] or use underscore _.first(array)

Answer (score 2):

As in the mongo version you need to provide both sort and limit options if you want to both sort and limit the objects returned.  Both are described in the [meteor docs on find()](http://docs.meteor.com/#find).

If you want to return a cursor with one item that has the highest price then this should work:

```
Articles.find({},{limit: 1, sort: {price: -1}});
```

If you want the object itself then add fetch() or use findOne().  If you use findOne() then the limit option is redundant.